# Type checking with Flow

Tags: reactjs, redux, flowtype

I have I question. I wrote a Flow type checker for checking my reducer. There was an error can you explain to me what is the cause of the error. This is my code.

```
// @flow
import {SET_USER} from "./action-types";
import type {SetUserAction} from "./user-actions"; // export type SetUserAction = (user: User) => Action;
export type State = {
    +username: ?string,
    +firstName: ?string,
    +lastName: ?string,
    +email: ?string,
    avatar?: ?string,
}

export type Action = SetUserAction;

const initialState: State = {
    username: null,
    firstName: null,
    lastName: null,
    email: null,
    avatar: null,
};

type Reducer = (state: State, action: Action) => State;

const userReducer:Reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_USER:
            return {...action.payload};
        default:
            // (action: empty);
            return state;
    }
};

export {userReducer};
```

This is errors.

*Error ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- src/redux/User/user-actions.js:25:48

Cannot assign function to `setUser` because a call signature declaring the expected parameter / return type is missing

in object literal [1] but exists in `SetUserAction` [2] in the return value.

   src/redux/User/user-actions.js:25:48

   25| export const setUser: SetUserAction = user => ({type: SET_USER, payload: user});

                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ [1]

References:

   src/redux/User/user-actions.js:24:45

   24| export type SetUserAction = (user: User) => Action;

                                                   ^^^^^^ [2]

Error ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- src/redux/User/user-reducer.js:26:20

Cannot get `action.type` because property `type` is missing in statics of function type [1].
   src/redux/User/user-reducer.js:26:20

   26|     switch (action.type) {

                          ^^^^

References:

   src/redux/User/user-reducer.js:23:39

   23| type Reducer = (state: State, action: Action) => State;

                                             ^^^^^^ [1]

Error ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- src/redux/User/user-reducer.js:26:13

Property `type` is missing in statics of function type [1].

   src/redux/User/user-reducer.js:26:13

   26|     switch (action.type) {

                   ^^^^^^^^^^^

References:

   src/redux/User/user-reducer.js:23:39

   23| type Reducer = (state: State, action: Action) => State;

                                             ^^^^^^ [1]

Error ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- src/redux/User/user-reducer.js:28:31

Cannot get `action.payload` because property `payload` is missing in statics of function type [1].
   src/redux/User/user-reducer.js:28:31

   28|             return {...action.payload};

                                     ^^^^^^^

References:

   src/redux/User/user-reducer.js:23:39

   23| type Reducer = (state: State, action: Action) => State;

                                             ^^^^^^ [1]*

Answer (score 0):

Based on what is posted, it might be difficult to diagnose the full cause of the error. However one thing to check is that based on this line

```js
import type {SetUserAction} from "./user-actions"; // export type SetUserAction = (user: User) => Action;
```

you are defining the `SetUserAction` type as a function (probably an action creator) and later on you are aliasing `Action` to be the type `SetUserAction` which effectively means the action parameter in your reducer is a function.

```js
export type Action = SetUserAction;
```

Consequently, when you switch on `action.type`, there will be a type error because there is no `.type` property on the `SetUserAction` type.

Hope this helps. It might not be the full picture of why there are errors but it will certainly a reason some of the error.